# Matplotlib: How to get this legend more compact?

Tags: matplotlib

consider the legend of this plot:
[image: A plot with redundant legend entries]

As you can see, the entries for the symbol shapes are largely redundant because the three categories "EN", "TF", "VA" always map to the same shapes, regardless of color. I'd like to have only the three shapes in a neutral color, much like ggplot does this.

Here's what the DataFrame looks like:

```
>>> df1
            Monat  Kat          km
Jahr                              
2014 61  9.219178  NaN    22.19200
     51  9.219178  NaN    31.93280
     62  9.284932  NaN    53.49220
     52  9.383562  NaN    84.31150
     64  9.547945  NaN    98.45260
...           ...  ...         ...
2019 48  9.252055       3022.01829
     45  9.383562   VA  3090.01239
     28  9.613699   VA  3160.66279
     20  9.712329  NaN  3249.04139
     31  9.778082  NaN  3313.60969

[264 rows x 3 columns]
```

The relevant code snippet:

```
for g in df1.groupby(level="Jahr"):
    ax.step(g[1].Monat, g[1].km, label=g[0],
            color=color_dict[g[0]],
            where="post")
    for gg in g[1].groupby("Kat"):
        ax.scatter(gg[1].Monat, gg[1].km,
                label=gg[0],
                marker=marker_dict[gg[0]],
                color=color_dict[g[0]])
```

Comment: Just label the first loop of the "Kat" grouping..

Answer (score 0):

Call me, crazy. But can't you just exclude the `label` argument from `scatter` and then plot some dummy plots with the relevant markers?

So just exclude the `label=` from `ax.scatter` and then just:

```py
ax.plot([],[],label='FA')
ax.plot([],[],label='VE')
ax.plot([],[],label='IA')
```

Otherwise, you'd have to detect dynamically, if a marker already exists and keeping track of that is gonna be some annoying code. Does it have to be dynamic?